Generalization of Holder inequality for arbitrary finite products
Let $f_i \in L^{p_i}(X)$, i.e. $\|f_i\|_{p_i} < \infty$ for each $p_i$ where $\{p_i\}$ is a finite collection of reals in $[1, \infty]$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{p_i} = 1$. Then we have
$$\|\prod_{i=1}^N f_i\|_1 \leq \prod_{i=1}^N \|f_i\|_{p_i} $$
This seems to be what I would call a generalization of Holder's Inequality (for arbitrary finite products). Are there any resources out there that include a proof of such a generalization? If not, what steps should one take to tackle a proof of this?
An idea I had was to proceed by induction. This could be achieved by considering that the case for $N=2$ is already proved, hence the base case is already shown. All that remains from there is the inductive step.

I think it is in Alt - Linear Functional Analysis. Where in the induction step are you struggling?

Ah yes, it is 3.18 in the aforementioned book

@HyperbolicPDEfriend thanks. Is this book for free download somewhere or must one purchase it?

If you‘re enrolled in a university maybe you have online Access via Springer or can have a look in the university library. But I don‘t know of any free Download link :(
